# Strange power law growth in XY correlation function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, critical-phenomena

I ran into a somewhat strange inconsistency while calculating a correlation function in the XY model. Actually, this is really a correlation function in just a usual Gaussian theory, but let's imagine that we're talking about the XY model in the low temperature phase for motivation's sake.

The action of the theory is

$$ S[\theta(x)] = \frac{K}{2} \int d^2 x  \, (\nabla \theta)^2 $$

In the XY model $\theta$ is compact, but here let's imagine that it's just an ordinary noncompact field. Of course, we need to include a cutoff $\Lambda \sim 1/a$.

In textbooks (ex: Kardar, page 164), the correlation function $\langle e^{i [\theta(x) - \theta(0)]} \rangle$ is usually calculated. The result is

$$ \langle e^{i [ \theta(x) - \theta(0) ] } \rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2} \langle [\theta(x) - \theta(0)]^2 \rangle } = e^{- \frac{1}{2\pi K} \log(r/a) } = \Big( \frac{a}{r} \Big)^{1/2\pi K} $$

This quickly follows from the usual rules of Gaussian integration, and makes physical sense for $r \gg a$. However, the correlation function that's giving me trouble is $\langle e^{i [\theta(x) + \theta(0)]} \rangle$, with a $+$ instead of a $-$. My intuition is that this correlation function should go to zero as $x \rightarrow 0$, since $\langle e^{2i\theta} \rangle$ ought to be zero, and the correlation function should also go to zero at long distances. Instead, I'm finding the following strange result:

$$ \langle e^{i [\theta(x) + \theta(0)]} \rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2} \langle [\theta(x) + \theta(0)]^2 \rangle } = e^{ -2 \langle [\theta(0)]^2 \rangle } e^{\frac{1}{2} \langle [\theta(x) - \theta(0)]^2 \rangle } = e^{ -2 \langle [\theta(0)]^2 \rangle } \Big( \frac{r}{a} \Big)^{1/2\pi K} $$

where I just used translation invariance to say $\langle [\theta(x)]^2 \rangle = \langle [\theta(0)]^2 \rangle$ for convenience of writing, and I used the result from the previous calculation for $\langle [\theta(x) - \theta(0)]^2 \rangle$. This seems to be an incredibly troubling result: it says that the correlation blows up to infinity at large distances! Clearly, something about this chain of equalities makes no sense: we are taking an expectation value of something with modulus 1, and the second expression is even manifestly real and less than 1. What have I done wrong here? It can't have to do with the compactness of $\theta$, I could have framed this as an ordinary Gaussian theory from the start.

EDIT: In case anyone else finds this post while searching for how to evaluate the listed correlation function $\langle e^{i[\theta(x) + \theta(0)]} \rangle$, note that this expectation value is not invariant under a global shift $\theta(x) \rightarrow \theta(x) + \theta_0$, while the probability distribution is invariant. As a result, the expectation value vanishes:

$$ \langle e^{i[\theta(x) + \theta(0)]} \rangle = e^{2i \theta_0} \langle e^{i[\theta(x) + \theta(0)]} \rangle = 0 $$

Comment: The infinite-volume field does not exist in dimension 2, only the field of gradients does. So, the second identity in your last display is not legit. The finite-volume field does exist (with some suitable boundary condition), but is then not translation invariant anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment: why can't I just imagine a finite system with periodic boundary conditions? And even if I don't, translation invariance doesn't seem to be a key part of this argument: I would still get $\exp \{ \frac{1}{2} \langle [\theta(x) - \theta(0)]^2 \rangle \}$, which is the part that blows up.

Comment: 1) For unbounded spins, the finite-volume measure with periodic boundary condition does not exist (even the partition function does not exist: try to compute it for a system with even a single spin!). 2) The other factor is (formally) equal to $0$, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: I apologize, I still don't understand. 1) Perhaps you have something different in mind for the single-spin partition function, but wouldn't it just be a single Gaussian integral? I fail to see how this partition function could not exist for a properly discretized, finite size system: it's just a Gaussian integral of a finite number of variables. 2) I imagine your implication is that $\langle [\theta(0)]^2 \rangle$ is infinite. Again, how is this possible with a suitable cutoff?

Comment: No the Gaussian integral you have in mind is for the **massive** Gaussian free field, not the massless one. The energy only penalizes the gradients, not an overall vertical shift of all spins. This is really due to the fact the the uniform measure on the real line is not normalizable.

Comment: Any configuration of your spins $(\theta_i)$ has the same energy as the configuration $(\theta_i + c)$, where $c$ is an arbitrary real number. This makes the partition function infinite.

Comment: Concerning the variance of the field, it is infinite in dimension 1 and 2. This is a manifestation of the Mermin-Wagner theorem: the formal Hamiltonian is invariant under the shift of all spins. This is a continuous symmetry, which cannot be broken in dimension $1$ and $2$. See Chapters 8 and 9 in [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook). Of course, in the Gaussian model, you can directly compute the variance of the model with zero boundary condition and take the thermodynamic limit to see that the variance diverges. Or consider the massive model and let the mass vanish.

Comment: I see, that's a good point, thank you for the comments!